# HQL return List<MyClass> instead List<Object[]>

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hql

In my HQL:

```
@Query("SELECT count(a.age) as age, count(w.weight) as weight from animals a inner join weight_table w on a.id = w.id")
```

I want return it as: 
          `List<MyObject>` instead of `List<Object[]>`

I have this class:

```
public class MyObject {
     private int age;
     private int weight;

     // getters setters all args constructor
}
```

is there possible to cast this in my HQL using something like this:

```
SELECT new.com.cs.MyObject(age, weight) count(a.age) as age, count(w.weight) as weight from animals a inner join weight_table w on a.id = w.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [projection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections):

```
@Query("SELECT count(a.age) as age, count(w.weight) as weight from animals a inner join weight_table w on a.id = w.id")
public List<MyObject> myMethodNameDescribingFunctionality();
```

where `MyObject` could be an interface:

```
public interface MyObject {
    @Value("#{target.age}")
    int age();

    @Value("#{target.weight}")
    int weight;
}
```

Comment: You could simply define a getter for default mapping. For example: `int getAge(); int getWeight();`

Comment: In case, aliases differ, I made it error-prone. But, you, @sgflt, are absolutely right!

Comment: You return MyObject instead List<MyObject> which is required.

Answer (score 0):

for using custom class I use first to create a constructor for these attributes

```
public class MyObject {
     private int age;
     private int weight;
     public  MyObject(int age , int weight) {
         this.age=age;
         this.weight = weight; 
     }
}
```

after that, in hql u can call this constructor in the same order of values

```
@Query("SELECT new com.packagename.MyObject(count(a.age), count(w.weight)) from animals a inner join weight_table w on a.id = w.id")
```

you will return a list from MyObject objects